# How can I avoid IEnumerable nested in another IEnumerable using lambda expressions

Tags: c#, lambda, refactoring, ienumerable, nested-lists

I am refactoring some code that currently consists of a foreach inside another foreach to get a list of types. Later on on those types some action is performed.

At the moment I end with an `IEnumerable` inside another `IEnumerable`, I wanted to have the final list of types (e.g. IEnumerable or Type[]) to process.

How can I unwind my result, so that I don't have a nested `IEnumerable` (`IEnumerable` inside an `IEnumerable`)?

This is (simplified) my current code:

```
var types = assemblies.Select(asm => asm.GetExportedTypes()
                        .Where(t => typeof(IMyCustomValidator).IsAssignableFrom(t) && !t.IsInterface));
```

This results in `types` being of type  `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Type>>`.

I believe there should be a rather simple solution for this issue but I cannot get my head around it.

Comment: Using SelectMany reduces the two level array to one level.

Comment: Did you try use `selectmany` ?

Comment: Ah, wow,... this simple. I knew there should be an easy way but I believe I haven't used SelectMany before - now I do :-)

Comment: Somebody should post their comment as an answer.